# avoid blank line fputcsv file download code

Tags: file, csv, download, fputcsv

I am developing a page that will let user download some database results in csv. Everything is fine. But the csv file has a blank line that is an issue for the user. It is to be used with some application.

fputcsv($output,$list);
     }
    $stat = fstat($output);
    ftruncate($output,$stat['size']-1);

Comment: It is fixed already by adding exit(); before php closing tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add exit() before php closing tag